# Simplying $ie^{it}(1+e^{-it})^n$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Need some help simplifying $$ie^{it}(1+e^{-it})^n$$ where n is an integer, so I can integrate it between $0$ and $2\pi$

I tried using De Moivres Theorem but the 1+ didn't allow me too

Comment: I removed my answer, as that solution doesn't work for this form as I see it, and I'll need to think of another trick to make it work.

Comment: Newton's formula should be your way to go, I guess: $$(1+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}y^k$$

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, expand $(1+e^{-it})^n$ using the binomial theorem and integrate term by term. Most of the integrals will be $0$.

Comment: Integral of $e^{-kit}$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ is $0$? where k is an integer in the binomial expansion. So I get $2n \pi i$ as the answer? As the only integral is of n

Comment: ^What I said doesn't make too much sense lol . But I think this is correct so thanks for your help

Comment: @Jacob It makes sense, and your result is correct.

Comment: Nice work. Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 1):

$$ie^{it}\left(1+e^{it}\right)^n=ie^{it\left(1+\frac{n}2\right)}\left(e^{-\frac12it}+e^{\frac12it}\right)^n=ie^{it\left(1+\frac{n}2\right)}2^n\cos^n\left(\frac{t}2\right)$$

Comment: That is still quite hard to integrate but thanks for the expression

Comment: @Jacob I agree. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way I could use $|z|^2=|z|*|z\bar|$ to make the expression simpler or no?

Comment: @Jacob I don't think so. Mine is rather $(z+\overline z)^n$.